# method not being called in controller from ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

My get ajax request is not being called from the response of one post request. Below is the code

```
$("#buttonclick").on("click", function () {
    var projectCollection = "DefaultCollection";
    var project = $("#Configuration_iCodeProjectID").val();
    var definitionId = $("#buildDefinition").val();
    //if (validateTriggerNewBuild) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Operations/TriggerBuild",
        data: { "projectCollection": projectCollection, "project": project, "definitionId": definitionId },
        datatype: "application/json",
        success: function (data) {
            var buildId = $("#hdnBuildDefinitionId");
            buildId.text(data);
            startGetProgress();
        }
    })
    //}
});
function startGetProgress() {
    window.progressID = setInterval(getProgress(), 10000); // update progress every 10 seconds
}

function getProgress() {
    var buildId = $("#hdnBuildDefinitionId").text();

    $.getJSON('GetBuildLogs', function (data) {

    });
    private JsonResult GetBuildLogs() {
        //get the id for the currently running build

        //connect to the tfs service to get the logs

        //populate the textbox with the logs

        return Json(string.Empty, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Based on the button click i am trying to load values in the textarea, but my method is not being called. I am not sure whether this is possible or i there is more efficient way for this. Please provide your valuable suggestions.

Comment: Did you try checking if the response is a success response for the first AJAX request? Try adding a console.log statement and check.

Comment: Your trying to call a the action: `TriggerBuild` in controller `Operations` ?

Comment: yes, i am calling triggernewbuild and after getting success i am trying to call GetBuildLogs in Operations controller

Comment: Any console error ?

Comment: why `action` method is `private`?

Comment: `setInterval(getProgress, 10000);`

Comment: Thanks Muhammed, it was a blunder. making it public resolved the issue.

Comment: @Muhammed please post your answer in answer section for future reference .

Comment: What is the response in `console.log(data)` in the success function?

Answer (score 1):

Change `Action` method `access modifier` to public